# Dialog not correctly working after second call

Tags: angularjs

I want to pass an array to a Modal Dialog with a template.

As I only used AngularJS for today, 99% of the code is from the doc.

My current code which works for the first time opening the Dialog but not after:
(the md-option is empty and the buttons (close, confirm) don't work)

```
angular.module("materialExample").controller("calendarCtrl", function ($scope, $filter, $q, $timeout, $log, $mdDialog, MaterialCalendarData) {

$scope.showAdvanced = function(ev) {

$scope.data= ev;

$mdDialog.show({
    controller: DialogController,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    templateUrl: 'includes/dialog.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen ,// Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
    scope: $scope,
    resolve: {
        test: function() {
            return $scope.data;
        }
    }
})
    .then(function(answer) {
        $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
    }, function() {
        $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
    });
};

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $mdDialog.cancel();
    };

    $scope.answer = function(answer) {
        $mdDialog.hide(answer);
    };
}
}
```

And in the template dialog.tmpl.html

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.userState">
    <md-option ng-repeat="iter in data" ng-value="iter.value.date" >
    {{iter.value.date + ' ' + iter.value.type}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

Is this the right way to pass a variable? How do I fix the code so the DialogController works for consecutive opened Dialogs?

Removing

```
scope: $scope,
```

fixes the DialogController but I can't pass the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $mdDialog can be called with a **locals** attribute (uses a dict) in which you can give params :

```
$mdDialog.show({
controller: DialogController,
controllerAs: 'ctrl',
templateUrl: 'includes/dialog.tmpl.html',
parent: angular.element(document.body),
clickOutsideToClose:true,
fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen ,// Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
scope: $scope,
**locals: {element:$scope.element}**,
resolve: {
    test: function() {
        return $scope.data;
    }
}
```

})

and then your controller :

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myapp')
    .controller('mycontroller', mycontroller);

/* @ngInject */
function mycontroller($scope, $mdDialog, element) {
  $scope.element = element // now you can use $scope.element in this controller and it will work :)
  // what ever you need to do here
 ...
}
})()
```

Comment: Thank you! Searching for locals helped me a great deal. Now it works without the scope and resolve.